# unable Jupyter cloud notebook connecting with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jupyter-notebook, tcp

Unable to connect Jupyter cloud notebook/Google colab, with postgres installed on my laptop.

````
    hostname = 'localhost'
    dbname = 'postgres'
    usr = 'postgres'
    pwd = 'mypassword'
   conn = psycopg2.connect(host=hostname, database=dbname, user=usr, password=pwd)```



OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`


But it works when I use same code in Vscode...

Postgres is running in services.

in postgres.conf file, port is 5432

postgres version 15.3, pgadmin version 4 v7.1

please let me know if I am missing something. Okay please stackoverflow let me post now .
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, it seems like you are trying to connect to a local PostgreSQL server running on your laptop from a Jupyter cloud notebook or Google Colab.

The issue here is that Jupyter cloud notebooks (and Google Colab) run on remote servers, not on your local machine, so specifying "localhost" as the hostname in your connection string, it refers to the local machine where the code is being executed - in this case, the remote server running the Jupyter cloud notebook or Google Colab, not your laptop.

To connect to a PostgreSQL server running on your laptop from a Jupyter cloud notebook or Google Colab, you could run [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with/postgresql/) on your colab notebook `ngrok tcp 5432` and then use the ngrok link with the port to connect to colab.
[image: Ngrok on Colab]
[image: Ngrok address]

I tested it against a local instance on my machine with `jupyter-lab`

[image: Jupyter-Ngrok]